# Ubuntu 10.04 on vServer: SSHD fails to come up after apt-get upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, init

I have a vServer running Ubuntu Linux 10.04 LTS in a Parallels container. Yesterday, I updated packages using `apt-get upgrade`. After the upgrade, I could not longer log into the machine using SSH. I have retrieved /var/log/syslog using the management interface:

```
Feb 20 13:17:31 39032 syslogd 1.5.0#5ubuntu4: restart.
Feb 20 13:17:31 39032 named[7748]: starting BIND 9.7.0-P1 -u bind
Feb 20 13:17:31 39032 named[7748]: built with '--prefix=/usr' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--sysconfdir=/etc/bind' '--localstatedir=/var' '--enable-threads' '--enable-largefile' '--with-libtool' '--enable-shared' '--enable-static' '--with-openssl=/usr' '--with-gssapi=/usr' '--with-gnu-ld' '--with-dlz-postgres=no' '--with-dlz-mysql=no' '--with-dlz-bdb=yes' '--with-dlz-filesystem=yes' '--with-dlz-ldap=yes' '--with-dlz-stub=yes' '--with-geoip=/usr' '--enable-ipv6' 'CFLAGS=-fno-strict-aliasing -DDIG_SIGCHASE -O2' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions' 'CPPFLAGS='
Feb 20 13:17:31 39032 named[7748]: adjusted limit on open files from 1024 to 1048576
Feb 20 13:17:31 39032 named[7748]: found 1 CPU, using 1 worker thread
Feb 20 13:17:31 39032 named[7748]: using up to 4096 sockets
Feb 20 13:17:31 39032 named[7748]: loading configuration from '/etc/bind/named.conf'
Feb 20 13:17:31 39032 named[7748]: reading built-in trusted keys from file '/etc/bind/bind.keys'
Feb 20 13:17:31 39032 named[7748]: using default UDP/IPv4 port range: [1024, 65535]
Feb 20 13:17:31 39032 named[7748]: using default UDP/IPv6 port range: [1024, 65535]
Feb 20 13:17:31 39032 named[7748]: listening on IPv6 interfaces, port 53
Feb 20 13:17:31 39032 named[7748]: listening on IPv4 interface lo, 127.0.0.1#53
Feb 20 13:17:31 39032 named[7748]: generating session key for dynamic DNS
Feb 20 13:17:31 39032 named[7748]: automatic empty zone: 254.169.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 20 13:17:31 39032 named[7748]: automatic empty zone: 2.0.192.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 20 13:17:31 39032 named[7748]: automatic empty zone: 255.255.255.255.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Feb 20 13:17:31 39032 named[7748]: automatic empty zone: 0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.IP6.ARPA
Feb 20 13:17:31 39032 named[7748]: automatic empty zone: 1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.IP6.ARPA
Feb 20 13:17:31 39032 named[7748]: automatic empty zone: D.F.IP6.ARPA
Feb 20 13:17:31 39032 named[7748]: automatic empty zone: 8.E.F.IP6.ARPA
Feb 20 13:17:31 39032 named[7748]: automatic empty zone: 9.E.F.IP6.ARPA
Feb 20 13:17:31 39032 named[7748]: automatic empty zone: A.E.F.IP6.ARPA
Feb 20 13:17:31 39032 named[7748]: automatic empty zone: B.E.F.IP6.ARPA
Feb 20 13:17:31 39032 named[7748]: command channel listening on 127.0.0.1#953
Feb 20 13:17:31 39032 named[7748]: command channel listening on ::1#953
Feb 20 13:17:31 39032 named[7748]: zone 0.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
Feb 20 13:17:31 39032 named[7748]: zone 127.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
Feb 20 13:17:31 39032 named[7748]: zone 255.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
Feb 20 13:17:31 39032 named[7748]: zone localhost/IN: loaded serial 2
Feb 20 13:17:31 39032 named[7748]: running
Feb 20 13:17:31 39032 named[7748]: received control channel command 'reconfig'
Feb 20 13:17:31 39032 named[7748]: loading configuration from '/etc/bind/named.conf'
Feb 20 13:17:31 39032 named[7748]: reading built-in trusted keys from file '/etc/bind/bind.keys'
Feb 20 13:17:31 39032 named[7748]: using default UDP/IPv4 port range: [1024, 65535]
Feb 20 13:17:31 39032 named[7748]: using default UDP/IPv6 port range: [1024, 65535]
Feb 20 13:17:31 39032 named[7748]: reloading configuration succeeded
Feb 20 13:17:31 39032 named[7748]: any newly configured zones are now loaded
Feb 20 13:17:32 39032 named[7748]: received control channel command 'reconfig'
Feb 20 13:17:32 39032 named[7748]: loading configuration from '/etc/bind/named.conf'
Feb 20 13:17:32 39032 named[7748]: reading built-in trusted keys from file '/etc/bind/bind.keys'
Feb 20 13:17:32 39032 named[7748]: using default UDP/IPv4 port range: [1024, 65535]
Feb 20 13:17:32 39032 named[7748]: using default UDP/IPv6 port range: [1024, 65535]
Feb 20 13:17:32 39032 named[7748]: listening on IPv4 interface venet0:0, 62.141.39.32#53
Feb 20 13:17:33 39032 named[7748]: reloading configuration succeeded
Feb 20 13:17:33 39032 named[7748]: any newly configured zones are now loaded
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 libvirtd: 13:17:34.010: error : networkStartNetworkDaemon:954 : cannot create bridge 'virbr0': Package not installed 
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 libvirtd: 13:17:34.010: error : udevSetupSystemDev:1417 : Failed to get udev device for syspath '/sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id'  
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 libvirtd: 13:17:34.011: error : udevSetupSystemDev:1421 : Failed to get udev device for syspath '/sys/class/dmi/id'  
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 libvirtd: 13:17:34.011: warning : qemudStartup:1087 : Unable to create cgroup for driver: No such device or address 
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 libvirtd: 13:17:34.051: error : main:3154 : Driver state initialization failed 
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 libvirtd: 13:17:34.052: warning : qemudDispatchSignalEvent:385 : Shutting down on signal 3 
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 init: libvirt-bin main process (7853) terminated with status 1
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 init: libvirt-bin main process ended, respawning
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 libvirtd: 13:17:34.072: error : networkStartNetworkDaemon:954 : cannot create bridge 'virbr0': Package not installed 
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 libvirtd: 13:17:34.072: error : udevSetupSystemDev:1417 : Failed to get udev device for syspath '/sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id'  
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 libvirtd: 13:17:34.072: error : udevSetupSystemDev:1421 : Failed to get udev device for syspath '/sys/class/dmi/id'  
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 libvirtd: 13:17:34.072: warning : qemudStartup:1087 : Unable to create cgroup for driver: No such device or address 
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 libvirtd: 13:17:34.112: error : main:3154 : Driver state initialization failed 
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 libvirtd: 13:17:34.112: warning : qemudDispatchSignalEvent:385 : Shutting down on signal 3 
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 init: libvirt-bin main process (7875) terminated with status 1
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 init: libvirt-bin main process ended, respawning
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 libvirtd: 13:17:34.132: error : networkStartNetworkDaemon:954 : cannot create bridge 'virbr0': Package not installed 
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 libvirtd: 13:17:34.132: error : udevSetupSystemDev:1417 : Failed to get udev device for syspath '/sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id'  
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 libvirtd: 13:17:34.132: error : udevSetupSystemDev:1421 : Failed to get udev device for syspath '/sys/class/dmi/id'  
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 libvirtd: 13:17:34.133: warning : qemudStartup:1087 : Unable to create cgroup for driver: No such device or address 
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 libvirtd: 13:17:34.172: error : main:3154 : Driver state initialization failed 
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 libvirtd: 13:17:34.172: warning : qemudDispatchSignalEvent:385 : Shutting down on signal 3 
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 init: libvirt-bin main process (7893) terminated with status 1
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 init: libvirt-bin main process ended, respawning
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 libvirtd: 13:17:34.193: error : networkStartNetworkDaemon:954 : cannot create bridge 'virbr0': Package not installed 
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 libvirtd: 13:17:34.193: error : udevSetupSystemDev:1417 : Failed to get udev device for syspath '/sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id'  
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 libvirtd: 13:17:34.193: error : udevSetupSystemDev:1421 : Failed to get udev device for syspath '/sys/class/dmi/id'  
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 libvirtd: 13:17:34.194: warning : qemudStartup:1087 : Unable to create cgroup for driver: No such device or address 
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 libvirtd: 13:17:34.233: error : main:3154 : Driver state initialization failed 
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 libvirtd: 13:17:34.233: warning : qemudDispatchSignalEvent:385 : Shutting down on signal 3 
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 init: libvirt-bin main process (7917) terminated with status 1
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 init: libvirt-bin main process ended, respawning
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 libvirtd: 13:17:34.253: error : networkStartNetworkDaemon:954 : cannot create bridge 'virbr0': Package not installed 
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 libvirtd: 13:17:34.253: error : udevSetupSystemDev:1417 : Failed to get udev device for syspath '/sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id'  
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 libvirtd: 13:17:34.253: error : udevSetupSystemDev:1421 : Failed to get udev device for syspath '/sys/class/dmi/id'  
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 libvirtd: 13:17:34.254: warning : qemudStartup:1087 : Unable to create cgroup for driver: No such device or address 
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 libvirtd: 13:17:34.293: error : main:3154 : Driver state initialization failed 
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 libvirtd: 13:17:34.294: warning : qemudDispatchSignalEvent:385 : Shutting down on signal 3 
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 init: libvirt-bin main process (7951) terminated with status 1
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 init: libvirt-bin main process ended, respawning
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 libvirtd: 13:17:34.316: error : networkStartNetworkDaemon:954 : cannot create bridge 'virbr0': Package not installed 
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 libvirtd: 13:17:34.317: error : udevSetupSystemDev:1417 : Failed to get udev device for syspath '/sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id'  
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 libvirtd: 13:17:34.317: error : udevSetupSystemDev:1421 : Failed to get udev device for syspath '/sys/class/dmi/id'  
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 libvirtd: 13:17:34.317: warning : qemudStartup:1087 : Unable to create cgroup for driver: No such device or address 
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 init: libvirt-bin main process (7969) killed by SEGV signal
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 init: libvirt-bin main process ended, respawning
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 libvirtd: 13:17:34.357: error : networkStartNetworkDaemon:954 : cannot create bridge 'virbr0': Package not installed 
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 libvirtd: 13:17:34.358: error : udevSetupSystemDev:1417 : Failed to get udev device for syspath '/sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id'  
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 libvirtd: 13:17:34.358: error : udevSetupSystemDev:1421 : Failed to get udev device for syspath '/sys/class/dmi/id'  
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 libvirtd: 13:17:34.358: warning : qemudStartup:1087 : Unable to create cgroup for driver: No such device or address 
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 init: libvirt-bin main process (7989) killed by SEGV signal
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 init: libvirt-bin main process ended, respawning
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 libvirtd: 13:17:34.389: error : networkStartNetworkDaemon:954 : cannot create bridge 'virbr0': Package not installed 
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 libvirtd: 13:17:34.390: error : udevSetupSystemDev:1417 : Failed to get udev device for syspath '/sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id'  
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 libvirtd: 13:17:34.390: error : udevSetupSystemDev:1421 : Failed to get udev device for syspath '/sys/class/dmi/id'  
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 libvirtd: 13:17:34.390: warning : qemudStartup:1087 : Unable to create cgroup for driver: No such device or address 
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 libvirtd: 13:17:34.430: error : main:3154 : Driver state initialization failed 
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 libvirtd: 13:17:34.430: warning : qemudDispatchSignalEvent:385 : Shutting down on signal 3 
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 init: libvirt-bin main process (8003) terminated with status 1
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 init: libvirt-bin main process ended, respawning
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 libvirtd: 13:17:34.450: error : networkStartNetworkDaemon:954 : cannot create bridge 'virbr0': Package not installed 
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 libvirtd: 13:17:34.450: error : udevSetupSystemDev:1417 : Failed to get udev device for syspath '/sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id'  
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 libvirtd: 13:17:34.450: error : udevSetupSystemDev:1421 : Failed to get udev device for syspath '/sys/class/dmi/id'  
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 libvirtd: 13:17:34.451: warning : qemudStartup:1087 : Unable to create cgroup for driver: No such device or address 
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 libvirtd: 13:17:34.490: error : main:3154 : Driver state initialization failed 
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 libvirtd: 13:17:34.491: warning : qemudDispatchSignalEvent:385 : Shutting down on signal 3 
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 init: libvirt-bin main process (8024) terminated with status 1
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 init: libvirt-bin main process ended, respawning
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 libvirtd: 13:17:34.511: error : networkStartNetworkDaemon:954 : cannot create bridge 'virbr0': Package not installed 
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 libvirtd: 13:17:34.511: error : udevSetupSystemDev:1417 : Failed to get udev device for syspath '/sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id'  
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 libvirtd: 13:17:34.511: error : udevSetupSystemDev:1421 : Failed to get udev device for syspath '/sys/class/dmi/id'  
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 libvirtd: 13:17:34.512: warning : qemudStartup:1087 : Unable to create cgroup for driver: No such device or address 
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 libvirtd: 13:17:34.551: error : main:3154 : Driver state initialization failed 
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 libvirtd: 13:17:34.551: warning : qemudDispatchSignalEvent:385 : Shutting down on signal 3 
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 init: libvirt-bin main process (8041) terminated with status 1
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 init: libvirt-bin main process ended, respawning
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 libvirtd: 13:17:34.571: error : networkStartNetworkDaemon:954 : cannot create bridge 'virbr0': Package not installed 
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 libvirtd: 13:17:34.571: error : udevSetupSystemDev:1417 : Failed to get udev device for syspath '/sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id'  
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 libvirtd: 13:17:34.571: error : udevSetupSystemDev:1421 : Failed to get udev device for syspath '/sys/class/dmi/id'  
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 libvirtd: 13:17:34.572: warning : qemudStartup:1087 : Unable to create cgroup for driver: No such device or address 
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 init: libvirt-bin main process (8062) killed by SEGV signal
Feb 20 13:17:34 39032 init: libvirt-bin respawning too fast, stopped
Feb 20 13:17:36 39032 postfix/master[8183]: daemon started -- version 2.7.0, configuration /etc/postfix
Feb 20 13:17:36 39032 init: ssh pre-start process (9246) terminated with status 2
Feb 20 13:17:36 39032 xinetd[9256]: attribute: disable should not be in default section [file=/etc/xinetd.conf] [line=12]
Feb 20 13:17:36 39032 xinetd[9256]: Reading included configuration file: /etc/xinetd.d/chargen [file=/etc/xinetd.conf] [line=15]
Feb 20 13:17:36 39032 xinetd[9256]: Reading included configuration file: /etc/xinetd.d/daytime [file=/etc/xinetd.d/daytime] [line=28]
Feb 20 13:17:36 39032 xinetd[9256]: Reading included configuration file: /etc/xinetd.d/discard [file=/etc/xinetd.d/discard] [line=26]
Feb 20 13:17:36 39032 xinetd[9256]: Reading included configuration file: /etc/xinetd.d/echo [file=/etc/xinetd.d/echo] [line=25]
Feb 20 13:17:36 39032 xinetd[9256]: Reading included configuration file: /etc/xinetd.d/time [file=/etc/xinetd.d/time] [line=26]
Feb 20 13:17:36 39032 xinetd[9256]: removing chargen
Feb 20 13:17:36 39032 xinetd[9256]: removing chargen
Feb 20 13:17:36 39032 xinetd[9256]: removing daytime
Feb 20 13:17:36 39032 xinetd[9256]: removing daytime
Feb 20 13:17:36 39032 xinetd[9256]: removing discard
Feb 20 13:17:36 39032 xinetd[9256]: removing discard
Feb 20 13:17:36 39032 xinetd[9256]: removing echo
Feb 20 13:17:36 39032 xinetd[9256]: removing echo
Feb 20 13:17:36 39032 xinetd[9256]: removing time
Feb 20 13:17:36 39032 xinetd[9256]: removing time
Feb 20 13:17:36 39032 xinetd[9256]: xinetd Version 2.3.14 started with libwrap loadavg options compiled in.
Feb 20 13:17:36 39032 xinetd[9256]: Started working: 0 available services
Feb 20 13:17:36 39032 dovecot: Dovecot v1.2.9 starting up
Feb 20 13:17:37 39032 ntpdate[7717]: step-systime: Operation not permitted
Feb 20 13:17:38 39032 dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<jannik>, method=PLAIN, rip=95.223.204.111, lip=62.141.39.32, TLS
Feb 20 13:17:38 39032 dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<jannik>, method=PLAIN, rip=95.223.204.111, lip=62.141.39.32, TLS
Feb 20 13:17:39 39032 ntpdate[9325]: step-systime: Operation not permitted
Feb 20 13:17:39 39032 dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<jannik>, method=PLAIN, rip=95.223.204.111, lip=62.141.39.32, TLS
Feb 20 13:17:39 39032 dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<jannik>, method=PLAIN, rip=95.223.204.111, lip=62.141.39.32, TLS
Feb 20 13:17:47 39032 ntpdate[9360]: step-systime: Operation not permitted
Feb 20 13:18:05 39032 dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<jannik>, method=PLAIN, rip=95.223.204.111, lip=62.141.39.32, TLS
```

The only ssh-relevant message in the log file is:

```
Feb 20 13:17:36 39032 init: ssh pre-start process (9246) terminated with status 2
```

I have booted the server using the rescue environment, SSH'd into that, bind-mounted proc into the original environment and chrooted into the original environment. In this way, I was able to call `/usr/sbin/sshd` to start an ssh daemon on a different port (since the rescue environment was already running `sshd` on `22`) and verify that connecting there works, so the problem seems to be with the `init` configuration.

However, invoking `/etc/init.d/ssh start`fails with the following message:

```
root@39032:/# /etc/init.d/ssh start
: not foundt/ssh: 3:
```

What could be the problem here? What does the error message in the syslog mean? How can I get more detailed information about the problem? Do the messages about libvirtd matter?